# How to do text classification for label using tensorflow lite model android?

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite, text-classification, google-mlkit

Actually i want tflite model of topic classification for android ML. There is lot of reference for sentimental analysis but none for topic level classification

Comment: ML Kit does not currently support text classification.  Here are some relevant links to help you search such models: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/text_classification/overview, or this: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tutorials/model_maker_text_classification

Comment: ok thank you first of all, The above links are for sentimental analysis based on the movie review but in my case i want to train the model with categarized dataset similar like image classification but with text : https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/images/classification.ipynb

Comment: This example was implemented with kotlin in android using a spam csv dataset https://towardsdatascience.com/spam-classification-in-android-with-tensorflow-lite-cde417e81260